# Custom ActionBar theme not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to customize the look and feel of an action bar and it doesn't seem to work.  The background is showing up grey when i am specifically setting it to a red.

**my build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eliddell.rapsheet"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eliddell.rapsheet" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**main activity**

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

if i update my styles to:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

then i briefly see the color change but the app crashes:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out and thank you all for your help.  The problem was my styles xml was pointing to "android:background" and "android:actionBarStyle"  but with the support library in place the "android:" gets dropped..

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>



<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/sapient_heat</item>

    <item name="background">@color/red</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    } else {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#ff0000")));
        actionBar.show();
    }

}
```

use ActionBar after SDK version 11,get the instance of ActionBar than do what ever u want

Comment: are you saying don't use themes?

Answer (score 0):

Use theme in android manifest as:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and in activity extends it as

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
```

Inflate custom view for action bar as:

```
// Inflate your custom layout
        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar_layout,
                null);
        //Set Custom ActionBar
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

where actionbar_layout is a layout xml for your actionbar

Comment: Have you used AppTheme in ur android manifest. & put this code in onCreate() ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Comment: Use this style <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

Comment: actionbaractivity won't resolve.. i am not understanding your solution

Comment: that changes the whole activity background not the action bar

Comment: Inflate a custom view as: '// Inflate your custom layout
     final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
             R.layout.actionbar_layout,
             null);
     //Set Custom ActionBar
  actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
     actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
     actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
     actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);'

Comment: that is not what developer.android says to do.. this is a mess